# To display 10th day of next month

Tags: php

I'm looking to display 10th day of next month.

Here's the piece of code I have which displays first day of next month. How can I modify this to get 10th day of next month.

```
if ($MyRow['daysbeforedue'] > 0) {
                /* Make a due date form trandate plus terms */
                $dateDue = date_create($MyRow['trandate']);
                date_add($dateDue, date_interval_create_from_date_string( ($MyRow['daysbeforedue'].' days')));
                $dateDue->modify( 'first day of this month' );
                $formatedDueDate =date_format($dateDue, 'm/d/Y');

            } 
            else { //More than 1 month
                /* Make a due date form trandate plus terms */
                $dateDue = date_create($MyRow['trandate']);
                date_add($dateDue, date_interval_create_from_date_string( ('1 month')));
                date_add($dateDue, date_interval_create_from_date_string( ($MyRow['dayinfollowingmonth'].' days')));
                $dateDue->modify( 'first day of this month' );
                $formatedDueDate = date_format($dateDue, 'm/d/Y');
                //$formatedDueDate = '';
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this:[DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

For example,

```
 $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');      // First day of month.
 $date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));    // Adding 10 days
 echo $date->format('m/d/Y');             // 1/11/2000
```